# How to break out of loop if a function returned a value

Tags: c++, function, for-loop

This is the function:

```
void LoseRollDice(int Result1, int Result2, int i)
{
    if (i == 1 && (Result1 == 2 || Result1 == 3 || Result1 == 12))
    {
        cout << "You Lose." << endl;
        return;
    }
    else if (i == 1 && (Result2 == 2 || Result2 == 3 || Result2 == 12))
    {
        cout << "Computer Loses." << endl;
        return;
    }
    if (Result1 == 7 && i > 1)
    {
        cout << "You Lose." << endl;
        return;
    }
    if (Result2 == 7 && i > 1)
    {
        cout << "Computer Loses." << endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

And here i used it:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter 1 to play, or 2 to exit: ";
    cin >> chose;
    cout << endl;
    if (chose == 1)
    {
        ResultPlayer = RollDice();
        ResultComputer = RollDice();
        DisplayDice(ResultPlayer, ResultComputer, i); 
        cout << endl;
        LoseRollDice(ResultPlayer, ResultComputer, i);
        // if the player lose, how to break after this function if the condition is true in it??
        WinRollDice(ResultPlayer, ResultComputer, i, SumPlayer, SumComputer);
    }
    else break;
}
```

How to break out of for loop if the condition is true in the function?
If i put break after the function in the loop it will break out of the loop even if the condition is not met

Comment: You need to have the function return something and based on what it returns continue or end the loop.

Comment: i thought  about to do like what you said, but i think it's not the best way to break !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change LoseRollDice to:

```
bool LoseRollDice(int Result1, int Result2, int i)
    {
    if (i == 1 && (Result1 == 2 || Result1 == 3 || Result1 == 12))
    {
        cout << "You Lose." << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else if (i == 1 && (Result2 == 2 || Result2 == 3 || Result2 == 12))
    {
        cout << "Computer Loses." << endl;
        return true;
    }
    if (Result1 == 7 && i > 1)
    {
        cout << "You Lose." << endl;
        return true;
    }
    if (Result2 == 7 && i > 1)
    {
        cout << "Computer Loses." << endl;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then your other code to:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter 1 to play, or 2 to exit: ";
    cin >> chose;
    cout << endl;
    if (chose == 1)
    {
        ResultPlayer = RollDice();
        ResultComputer = RollDice();
        DisplayDice(ResultPlayer, ResultComputer, i); 
        cout << endl;
        if (LoseRollDice(ResultPlayer, ResultComputer, i))
            break;
        WinRollDice(ResultPlayer, ResultComputer, i, SumPlayer, SumComputer);
    }
    else break;
}
```

Comment: @OlegGrytsenko What about you saying *i thought about to do like what you said, but i think it's not the best way to break !*?

Answer (score 0):

Douglas Dawson's answer is correct.  If you REALLY REALLY REALLY wanted that method to be void, you could also have the method throw an Exception, then catch the exception outside of the loop.  Thats an absolutely terrible way of implementing it though.

Or you could catch it in the loop and call `break;`

Answer (score 0):

Or use pointer... Send the same as parameter in function.. Change the pointer value inside if.. After that if you call function check point.. If that's changed means if had been called.. You can break your loop.